# Marginalization - Flipping coins

Tags: probability

A coin machine spits out a coin with a random bias Q. Q = q means
that the probability of heads for that coin is q. The PDF of Q is
fQ(q) = 2q for 0 ≤ q ≤ 1. Jack tosses the coin once, and it lands
heads. He then tosses the coin again. What is the probability that it
will land heads again the second time, given that it landed heads the
ﬁrst time?

**Step 1:**

```
     P( H1 & H2)
   ---------------
       P( H1 )
```

**Step 2:**

The solution manual says to use `the joint distribution of H1 and Q and marginalize over Q` which doesn't make sense because marginalization formula is as follows.

[image]

*Here is where I am stuck logically. In order to solve this, we have to integrate over p(h1, q)? I am not sure how to apply this equation to solve the problem?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we have three random variables. $C_1$,$C_2$ (with domain $\{0,1\}$, where $0$ means head) are the results of the two coin flips, and $Q$ (with domain $[0,1]$) is the bias of the coin. We know the CDF and density of $Q$, which are $$
  F_Q(x) = q^2 ,\, f_Q(x) = 2q
$$
and the *conditional probabilities* (this is an actual probability, not a density, because $C_i$ is a discrete random variable) $$
  P(C_i = 0 \mid Q = q) = q \text{.}
$$ 
We want to find $$
  P(C_2 = 0 \mid C_1 = 0) = \frac{P(C_1=0,C_2 = 0)}{P(C_1 = 0)} \text{.}
$$

Let's first find $P(C_1 = 0)$. We *marginalize* the condition $Q=q$ away by averaging over all possible values of $Q$. In other words, we "sum" (integrate, actually) up all the conditional probabilities $P(C_1 = 0 \mid Q = q)$, weighting each one with the "likelyhood" of that $q$ (density of $F_Q$ at $q$, actually). We get $$
  P(C_1 = 0) = \int_{0}^1 \underbrace{P(C_1=0 \mid Q = q)}_{\text{probability for a specific $q$}} \overbrace{f_Q(q)}^{\text{likelyhood of $q$}}\,dq = \int_0^1 q\cdot 2q \,dq = \frac{2}{3} \text{.}
$$
Doing the same for $P(C_1 = 0,C_2 = 0)$ yields $$
  P(C_1 = 0, C_2 = 0) = \int_{0}^1 P(C_1=0,C_2 = 0 \mid Q = q) \cdot f_Q(q)\,dq = \int_0^1 q^2\cdot 2q \,dq = \frac{1}{2} \text{.}
$$
Thus, $$
  P(C_2 = 0 \mid C_1 = 0) = \frac{P(C_1=0,C_2 = 0)}{P(C_1 = 0)} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2} = \frac{3}{4} \text{.}
$$

Note that we *had* to compute $P(C_1 = 0,C_2 = 0)$, i.e it is *not* true here that $P(C_1 = 0,C_2 = 0) = P(C_1 = 0)^2$, even though $C_1$ and $C_2$ obviously share the same distribution. But they are not *independent*, because didn't pick a new coin for the second coin flip, but rather re-used the old one. Thus, some information "carries over" from the first coin flip to the second. In fact, we can now easily compute the probability of seeing $n$ heads in a row if we re-use the same coin over and over, which is $$
  P(C_1,\ldots,C_n = 0) = \int_0^1 q^n \cdot 2q \,dq = \frac{2}{n+2}.
$$
Note that this decays *much slower* than the probability of seeing head $n$ times using a *different* coin each time, which (we may assume independence now) is $$
  \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \text{.}
$$
The reason is that if we saw head $n$ times, for a relatively large $n$, the coin will quite probably be biased in favour of head, and so subsequently seeing head is much more likely.

Comment: I think you mean 3/4 not 1/3. Also why do you "away by averaging over all possible values." I am asking because the formula doesn't really have that. What would happen if I don't. In other words, what does it mean when I don't do that?

Comment: @mk1 Yup, should have been $\frac{3}{4}$, fixed now. I tried to explain the averaging in a bit more detail, and annotated the factors in the integral to show what's what. Does that help?

Comment: I hate to say this, but I am still confused. But please do explain. Everything makes sense except for 1 thing. In the marginalization equation, there is no `q` as you mentioned in `q * 2q dq`, instead shouldn't it be `2q * dq`. I am talking about the equation I referred to in my original question. In terms of logic, this makes sense, but in terms of the marginalization equation, I don't see the joint PDF being integrated in your solution

Comment: To explain in more detail, I don't see something like `f(c1) = integral f(q, c1) dq`

Comment: $P(C_1 = 0) = \int_0^1 P(C_1=0 \mid Q=q) f_Q(q) \,dq$ basically has that form. There is no parameter $c_1$ because we only need the value for $C_1=0$, i.e. *our* integral looks more like $p_0 = \int p(0,y) \,dy$